# How to search a keyword then list all lines about this keyword?

Tags: shell

I use standard shell to write a phone book program which can add, delete and search contacts you looking for. 
I store the information of one contact by using 4 variable, name, address, city and phonenumber. I put them into a txt file line by line. When I do the search, for example:

```
Bill
2 wood st.
city
123-4323
```

when I search no matter Bill or wood or 4323, I need to print all these 4 lines.
sed and awk are not allowed to use, how to do it?

I used grep which can only output one line.

```
echo -e "\nEnter name to look up: \c"
read search
grep -i $search book
```

Comment: You could do `grep -i -C3 "$search" book` to get +- 3 lines of context, so you'd be sure to show the complete record. If you want the output to be tidier than that, there's more work to be done. Also, make sure you quote your variables.

Comment: Assuming you have control over the file format, consider adding a separator between records (e.g., '===', or similar). It will make processing of records much easier. Choose  a separator that will not appear in normal data

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk program to replace grep:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

read -rp 'Enter a search term: ' search

awk -v search="$search" '
  # read 4 lines as a "record"
  { record = $0; for (i=1; i<=3; i++) { getline; record = record RS $0 } }
  # do the case insensitive pattern match
  tolower(record) ~ tolower(search) { print record }
' book
```

Comment: bro, I now meet an other problem, I use grep -i -C3 "$search" book, if I search the phone number, the information of the next contact will be print out. any way to avoid this happen? btw there is a newline between each contact, anyway to stop when meet the newline. Still no using awk. really dont know why my professor dont allow to use awk or sed.

Comment: You should put important details like "blank line between records" up in the question. What tools *are* you allowed to use?

Comment: just standard shell